# How to assign ACM Certificate to Elastic Beanstalk security group?

Tags: domain-name-system, amazon-route53, elastic-beanstalk, amazon-acm

**Stack**

- Elastic Beanstalk
- AWS Route 53 for DNS.
- AWS Certificate Manager for SSL Cert.

---

**What I have done**

I have added the CNAME for the certificate (Through the wizard provided by AWS for Route 53).

I have added an inbound rule on the load balancer where the source is anywhere and the port is https(443).

I have added both the www and non-www domains when generating the certificate.

---

**What works**

Going to http://example.com works.

---

**What doesn't work**

Going to https://exmaple.com throws ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED.

---

This leads me to believe my Load Balancer Security Group entry is incorrect.

**Questions**

1. How do I *correctly* assign my ACM Certificate to my Elastic Beanstalk load balance Security Group?
2. Is there something that I am missing?
3. How long does it take for a change to the security group to resolve?

Comment: First of all, SSL certificates are not assigned to security groups, they are assigned to ELB/ALB/Target groups. But you should allow port 443 in your load balancer security group, that's for sure.

Comment: I have definitely allowed port 443 on the load balancer incoming. Is there anything else that could be stopping it from loading?

Comment: Did you enable HTTPS listener on your load balancer? That `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` suggests that the socket on port 443 isn't even opened.

Comment: I have updated this and made progress... Now there is a request timeout.